# Automake conditional compilation from C or Objective-C sources

Tags: autoconf, automake

I'm using the following to do conditional compilation in automake of the amhello example program [1]:

In `configure.ac`:

```
AC_INIT([amhello], [1.0], [bug-automake@gnu.org])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_OBJC
build_linux=no
build_windows=no
build_mac=no
AC_CANONICAL_HOST
case "${host_os}" in
    cygwin*|mingw*)
        build_windows=yes;;
    darwin*)
        build_mac=yes;;
    *)
        build_linux=yes;;
esac
AM_CONDITIONAL([LINUX], [test "$build_linux" = "yes"])
AM_CONDITIONAL([WINDOWS], [test "$build_windows" = "yes"])
AM_CONDITIONAL([MACOS], [test "$build_mac" = "yes"])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
 Makefile
 src/Makefile
])
AC_OUTPUT
```

In `src/Makefile.am`:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello
hello_SOURCES = main.c
if MACOS
    hello_SOURCES += hello-mac.m
endif
if LINUX
    hello_SOURCES += hello-linux.c
endif
```

It works as expected except for one issue - even when compiling on Linux, it tries to use the Objective-C build suite instead of the C one. A side effect of this is that OBJCFLAGS gets used instead of CFLAGS, which is counter-intuitive given that no Objective-C source code is being compiled when built for Linux.  A demonstration:

```
$ OBJCFLAGS="-DOBJCFLAGS" CFLAGS="-DCFLAGS" ./configure
...
$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/src'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -DCFLAGS -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.c
mv -f .deps/main.Tpo .deps/main.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -DCFLAGS -MT hello-linux.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/hello-linux.Tpo -c -o hello-linux.o hello-linux.c
mv -f .deps/hello-linux.Tpo .deps/hello-linux.Po
gcc  -DOBJCFLAGS   -o hello main.o  hello-linux.o  
...
```

From the generated `src/Makefile`:

```
...
hello$(EXEEXT): $(hello_OBJECTS) $(hello_DEPENDENCIES) $(EXTRA_hello_DEPENDENCIES)
    @rm -f hello$(EXEEXT)
    $(AM_V_OBJCLD)$(OBJCLINK) $(hello_OBJECTS) $(hello_LDADD) $(LIBS)
...
```

Is there a good way to have the C compiler / CFLAGS be used when building for Linux and have the Objective-C compiler / OBJCFLAGS only be used when building for MacOS (when the Objective-C source file is to actually be built)?  I tried using both approaches to conditional compilation described in [2] but both exhibit the same behavior.

[1] https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Creating-amhello.html#Creating-amhello

[2] https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Conditional-Sources.html#Conditional-Sources

Comment: Have you tried calling `AC_LANG` with an appropriate value from the case statements?

Answer (score 0):

The OBJCFLAGS are used only at link time, because automake selects the Objective-C linker if it sees any Objective-C source files. See this page in the [automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/How-the-Linker-is-Chosen.html).

You can use a per-target `_LINK` variable to override the default linker selection. In Makefile.am, you can write this, to force the use of the C linker:

```
hello_LINK = $(LINK)
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect that if you tell automake to build different executables for Linux, Windows and MacOS instead of building the same executable with some OS specific variants, automake should not try an Objective-C compiler for the Linux and Windows versions as long as the Linux and Windows do not use any Objective-C sources.

**NOTE: This is speculative, verification is needed.**

Now... you will need to call these three executables three distinct names if you are going to define them in the same `Makefile.am`, or define them in multiple `Makefile.am` files. I can see a few possibilities to do that, and you may need to add `subdir-objects` to `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([...])` and re-run `autoreconf`.

Note that I have not tested any of this, as I have no idea about how to write Objective-C code. If you happen to have your project available somewhere to look (with maybe a proof-of-concept `hello-windows.c` using winapi, and absolutely `hello-macos.m` using MacOS APIs), I can try to figure out which of the following proposals works best.

- Use recursive make and `src/linux/hello`, `src/windows/hello`, `src/macos/hello` with one `Makefile.am` each, and move the OS-specific `hello-$OS.*` into the appropriate subdirectory:

  ```
  # src/linux/Makefile.am
  if LINUX
  bin_PROGRAMS = hello
  hello_SOURCES = hello-linux.c ../main.c
  endif
  ```

  ```
  # src/macos/Makefile.am
  if MACOS
  bin_PROGRAMS = hello
  hello_SOURCES = hello-macos.m ../main.c
  endif
  ```

  ```
  # src/windows/Makefile.am
  if WINDOWS
  bin_PROGRAMS = hello
  hello_SOURCES = hello-windows.c ../main.c
  # special rules to build object from resource file and adding it
  endif
  ```

  I do not like source files beginning with `../`, though. And the less recursive make we use, the better on multicore machines.
- Use non-recursive make for the three executables built as `src/linux/hello`, `src/windows/hello`, `src/macos/hello` with one `Makefile-files` file each, all included from `src/Makefile.am`, moving the OS specific sources to the OS specific subdirectory:

  ```
  # src/linux/Makefile-files -*- makefile-automake -*
  if LINUX
  bin_PROGRAMS += linux/hello
  linux_hello_SOURCES = linux/hello-linux.c main.c
  endif
  ```

  ```
  # src/macos/Makefile-files -*- makefile-automake -*
  if MACOS
  bin_PROGRAMS += macos/hello
  macos_hello_SOURCES = macos/hello-macos.m main.c
  endif
  ```

  ```
  # src/windows/Makefile-files -*- makefile-automake -*
  if WINDOWS
  bin_PROGRAMS += windows/hello
  windows_hello_SOURCES = windows/hello-windows.c main.c
  # special rules to build object from resource file and adding it
  endif
  ```

  ```
  # src/Makefile.am
  bin_PROGRAMS =
  include linux/Makefile-files
  include macos/Makefile-files
  include windows/Makefile-files
  ```

  I would write the `Makefile-files` files using `%reldir%` and `%canon_reldir%` (or `%D%` and `%C%`).

  This allows OS specific files and build rules (e.g. Windows resource files and the rules to compile them and link them to the Windows executable) to be all neatly put into the OS specific subdirectory.

  Probably my preferred option for the longer term.
- Just call the executables `linux/hello`, `windows/hello`, and `macos/hello` from `src/Makefile.am` without moving the sources or the build rules away from `src/`:

  ```
  # src/Makefile.am
  bin_PROGRAMS =

  if LINUX
  bin_PROGRAMS += linux/hello
  linux_hello_SOURCES = hello-linux.c main.c
  endif

  if MACOS
  bin_PROGRAMS += macos/hello
  macos_hello_SOURCES = hello-macos.m main.c
  endif

  if WINDOWS
  bin_PROGRAMS += windows/hello
  windows_hello_SOURCES = hello-windows.c main.c
  # special rules to build object from resource file and adding it
  endif
  ```

  If there is a lot of OS specific source files and rules all in the single directory `src/` and its `src/Makefile.am`, this might become difficult to read.

  My preferred option for a quick minimum working example.
- Call the executables `hello-linux`, `hello-windows`, `hello-macos` from `src/Makefile.am` and then deal with installing the different executables as `hello` or `hello.exe` in install-hooks and the like.

  I would avoid this as those hooks and related stuff are non-trivial to get right.

It still needs to be checked whether `configure` will actually succeed when building for Linux and Windows without an Objective-C compiler to be found.